# What is the alternative to the deprecated 'GoogleCredential'?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'd been employing the following Java method to set a bucket notification in GCS.

```
private void setBucketNotification(String bucketName, String topicId) {

List<String> eventType = new ArrayList<>();
eventType.add("OBJECT_FINALIZE");

try {
  Notification notification = new Notification();
  notification.setTopic(topicId);
  notification.setEventTypes(eventType);
  notification.setPayloadFormat("JSON_API_V1");

  final GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential
      .fromStream(Objects.requireNonNull(classloader.getResourceAsStream("Key.json")))
      .createScoped(Collections.singletonList(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL));  

  final com.google.api.services.storage.Storage myStorage = new com.google.api.services.storage.Storage.Builder(
      new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), googleCredential).build();

  Notification v = myStorage.notifications().insert(bucketName, notification).execute();

} catch (IOException e) {
  log.error("Caught an IOException {}",e);
  }
}
```

It's been working fine so far, but lately, I'm getting a complaint regarding the deprecation of `GoogleCredential` class, and tried doing some research with a hope to find a possible replacement, but couldn't find anything. Can anyone help me point in the right direction?

Comment: Where are you seeing that `GoogleCredential` is deprecated?

Comment: perhaps you need to change the library you're using?

google-auth-library-java or com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v1-rev155-1.25.0

Comment: @JohnHanley The same place where it's being initialized.

Comment: Please include the exact message in your question. My builds do not show a deprecated message. Which Java version and JDK are you using?

Comment: @JohnHanley It Just said that 'com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential is deprecated'. I don't know how exact and clear I could be apart from this. I'm using java version "1.8.0_212".

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you accept it, so it gains greater visibility for other community users? Thanks @RoshanUpreti

Answer (score 56, accepted):

After a while of looking around, I managed to fix it, using `GoogleCredentials` and `HttpRequestInitializer`. The code changes are as follows.

```
final GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential
  .fromStream(Objects.requireNonNull(classloader.getResourceAsStream("Key.json")))
  .createScoped(Collections.singletonList(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL));

final com.google.api.services.storage.Storage myStorage = new com.google.api.services.storage.Storage.Builder(
      new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), googleCredential).build();
```

becomes

```
final GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = serviceAccountCredentials
                    .createScoped(Collections.singletonList(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL));
            HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(googleCredentials);        

final com.google.api.services.storage.Storage myStorage = new com.google.api.services.storage.Storage.Builder(
                new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), requestInitializer).build();
```

Comment: Thanks, @Roshan! The tricky part for me was how to get the `HttpRequestInitializer` from the `GoogleCredentials`; googling for it brought me here :)

Comment: How do you get the service account credentials using a p12 private key file?

Comment: @insa_c Why don't you use the `json` file with `ServiceAccountCredentials`, like this:
`ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(Objects.requireNonNull(classloader.getResourceAsStream("Key.json")))                    .createScoped(Collections.singletonList(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL));`

Comment: `HttpCredentialsAdapter` is all I needed, thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Curious to know how you figured out the `HttpCredentialsAdapter` constructor part...

Answer (score 12):

You can find an alternative solution as being posted on the **[Google APIs Github repository commits](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/commit/45825c4157eee2a7254817b1aae9aa63ba726726)**.

> Please use **[Google Auth Library for Java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java)** for handling Application Default Credentials and other non-OAuth2 based authentication.

Explicit Credential Loading sample code:

> To get Credentials from a Service Account JSON key use GoogleCredentials.fromStream(InputStream) or GoogleCredentials.fromStream(InputStream, HttpTransportFactory). Note that the credentials must be refreshed before the access token is available.

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("/path/to/credentials.json"));
credentials.refreshIfExpired();
AccessToken token = credentials.getAccessToken();
// OR
AccessToken token = credentials.refreshAccessToken();
```

Comment: this is a link-only answer - even though it provides the proper information i strongly would hope you could add an example on how to use the api (-1)

Comment: Hey @MartinFrank. You are totally right. Hyperlinks can be modified or broken. It's always best practice to add some example code or text to further explain. It's been quite some time since I posted this answer. It was during my Stackoverflow beginnings, and I was not aware of such things. Please bear with me on this one. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: i'll provide right now an answer - but i would certainly remove my -1 if you change your answer (at least slightly)

Comment: @MartinFrank Perfect! I believe my edited answer now provides a basic example of Credential Loading and how deprecated `GoogleCredential` class changed into `GoogleCredentials` Thanks.

Comment: While this answer shows some ways to work with `GoogleCredentials`, it does **not** show how to obtain an `HttpRequestInitializer` from it, which is what's necessary in order to use it as a replacement for the deprecated `GoogleCredential` in the code in the question (and which is explained in @Roshan's answer).

Comment: When `GoogleCredential` from `com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2` works with the Firebase API, `GoogleCredentials` from `com.google.auth.oauth2` doesn't. It seems that they aren't exactly equivalent.

Comment: `com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.Builder` has `setServiceAccountUser(String serviceAccountUser)` which sets the email address of the user the application is trying to impersonate, but `com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials` doesn't. Please somebody share an example how to do impersonation with this new  `GoogleCredentials`

Answer (score 4):

I had to solve similar task when using Google Admin SDK API and
com.google.api.services.admin.directory.Directory was needed.

```
    final ServiceAccountCredentials serviceAccountCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromPkcs8(
            clientId,
            clientEmail,
            serviceAccountPkcs8Key,
            serviceAccountPkcs8Id,
            Arrays.asList(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER_READONLY));
    final GoogleCredentials delegatedCredentials = serviceAccountCredentials.createDelegated(delegatedUserEmail);
    HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(delegatedCredentials);

    Directory directory = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, requestInitializer)
            .setApplicationName(applicationName)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `google-auth-library-oauth2-http` library

Code:

```
ServiceAccountCredentials getServiceAccountCredentials(String privateKeyJson) 
throws IOException {
   try (InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(privateKeyJson.getBytes())) {
      return ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(stream);
   }
}
```

```
ServiceAccountCredentials serviceAccountCredentials = getServiceAccountCredentials(privateKeyJson);
String privateKeyId = serviceAccountCredentials.getPrivateKeyId();
RSAPrivateKey key = (RSAPrivateKey)  serviceAccountCredentials.getPrivateKey();
```