# com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 137)): expected a valid value

Tags: java, api, google-drive-api, inputstream, jsonexception

I am using google drive rest api to fetch data from drive to my app. Whenever I tried to fetch the data into **inputStream**, got this error:

```
W/System.err:  com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 137)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
W/System.err:  at [Source: com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse$SizeValidatingInputStream@2975e41; line: 1, column: 2]
```

my code snippet:

```
GoogleCredential googleAccessCredential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, googleAccessCredential)
                                    .setApplicationName("Test")
                                    .build();
inputStream = drive.files().get("fileId").executeMediaAsInputStream();
```

I searched a lot but didn't get any feasible solution. I tried to change the header but got same error

```
inputStream = drive.files().get("fileId").setRequestHeaders(new HttpHeaders().setAccept("image/png")).executeAsInputStream();
```

I also tried with *"application/json"* and *"application/octet-stream"* headers.

**access token is given hard coded**

Comment: Can you provide the content of the lines that throw you errors? Why are you trying to hardocde the access token?

Comment: inputStream = drive.files().get("fileId").executeMediaAsInputStream(); this line is giving me the error. The file is a png image. As I want to show images from a specific drive to all the users, I'm giving the access token hard coded.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that an access token expires after 60 minutes? Maybe it would be easier to share this specific drive with all users of interest and letting them authenticate as themselves?

Comment: To exclude that the issue is token related:  is it only the request `inputStream = drive.files().get("fileId").executeMediaAsInputStream();` that errors, does another request (e.g. `drive.files().list()`) work correctly?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the fact of access token lifetime and I overcome that issue by generating new access token through refresh token when it is needed. Other requests are working fine. Only this request is giving me the error.

Comment: Try [executeMediaAndDownloadTo](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive) instead, or /and check if there is an incompatibility issue with the java version you are using.

Comment: Important:  GoogleCredential is deprectaed as you can verify [here](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.html), so on long term you have to come up with a different solution - see [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/commit/45825c4157eee2a7254817b1aae9aa63ba726726) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972607/what-is-the-alternative-to-the-deprecated-googlecredential)